# AngularJS service is not updating the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a service declared in my `application.js` file within my `AngularJS` project. It looks like this:

```
application.factory('interfaceService', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    var interfaceService = {};
    interfaceService.lang = "";
    interfaceService.dev = ""
    interfaceService.theme = "";
    interfaceService.integ = "";
    //For Integration Type
    interfaceService.demo = function (dev, theme, integ, lang) {
        this.dev = dev;
        this.theme = theme;
        this.integ= integ;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };
    interfaceService.broadcastItem = function () {
        $timeout(function(){
             $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
        });
    };
    return interfaceService;
});
```

I am using the above service to pass variables between 2 of my `Controllers`. The controller which calls the service is here:

```
        $scope.buildDemo = function () {
            interfaceService.demo(device, template, integ, language);
            $rootScope.template = template;
            $rootScope.themeFolder = template;
            $state.go("MainPage", {
               "themeName": $rootScope.themeFolder
            });
        }
```

That function is triggered when the user clicks on a div on my `view`

```
<div id='build-btn' ng-click='buildDemo()'>Go</div>
```

The problem I am having is that my view is not updating when I click on the button. I have to click on it a second time to see any changes. Would anyone know what is causing this? The URL updates and the new view comes onto the page but the elements that should be showing based on the parameters set in the service are not visible until I click on the "Go" button a second time.

Comment: when you click on the go button, it should change the route, load the template and controller that is associated with this route, execute the logic in this controller.. So when you click on Go button for the first time, any errors on your console? are you sure the correct template and controller has been loaded? if yes, how far into the controller did you get. I am just throwing out ideas for you to trace your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first click `handleBroadcast` event gets broadcasted and but haven't received by anyone, because when you press "GO" button, at that time state transition occurs and it loads template and its controller. When controller instantiated, it register the listener event using `$on` on `handleBroadcast` event.

I'd suggest you that to wait to broadcast an event till controller & its underlying view gets render. This can be done by taking advantage of promise returned by `$state.go` method. Which completes when transition succeeds.

**Code**

```
$scope.buildDemo = function() {
    //state transition started.
    $state.go("MainPage", {
        "themeName": $rootScope.themeFolder
    }).then(function() {
        //state transition completed
        //controller instance is available & listener is ready to listen
        interfaceService.demo(device, template, integ, language);
        $rootScope.template = template;
        $rootScope.themeFolder = template;
    });
}
```